# Customized system script printing exception？

Tags: linux, shell

When I run this script in the background, normally it prints every 600 seconds, but I don't know why the `dmesg` display looks like this, as if it's stacked together. My system is customized, not a distribution version. The file system is created using `busybox`.May I know how to troubleshoot this issue?

After comparative testing, it was found that it was due to `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches &` prevent `sleep 600` from taking effect. If it is blocked, `sleep 600` will take effect. Why?

autoCacheFree.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

drop_caches() {
    echo "Drop caches."
    sync
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches &
    return 0
}

while true; do
    sleep 600
    drop_caches
done
```

the information of `dmesg`:

```
...
[ 1405.880208] autoCacheFree.s (19284): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.895675] autoCacheFree.s (19286): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.911123] autoCacheFree.s (19288): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.926552] autoCacheFree.s (19290): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.941609] autoCacheFree.s (19292): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.957013] autoCacheFree.s (19294): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.972305] autoCacheFree.s (19296): drop_caches: 1
[ 1405.987799] autoCacheFree.s (19298): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.003028] autoCacheFree.s (19300): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.018418] autoCacheFree.s (19302): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.033637] autoCacheFree.s (19304): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.049015] autoCacheFree.s (19306): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.064032] autoCacheFree.s (19308): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.079359] autoCacheFree.s (19310): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.094496] autoCacheFree.s (19312): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.110246] autoCacheFree.s (19314): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.125805] autoCacheFree.s (19316): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.141808] autoCacheFree.s (19318): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.157118] autoCacheFree.s (19320): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.172632] autoCacheFree.s (19322): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.188490] autoCacheFree.s (19329): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.204322] autoCacheFree.s (19331): drop_caches: 1
[ 1406.220455] autoCacheFree.s (19333): drop_caches: 1
```